# Removing Default Properties in Serilog Output

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

In the Serilog output in a file, I see that the default is

```
{
    "Timestamp": "2016-05-28T21:21:59.0932348+08:00",
    "Level": "Information",
    "MessageTemplate": "Processed {@Number} records in {@Time} ms",
    "Properties": {
        "Number": 500,
        "Time": 120
    }
}
```

Is there a way to remove the Timestamp, level, messagetemplate, and properties so that I"m left with this only

```
{
    "Number": 500,
    "Time": 120
}
```

The Log.Logger is assigned as such

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Sink(new FileSink(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serilogPath"], new JsonFormatter(), null))
    .CreateLogger();
```

Thanks

Comment: It may depend on the sink and the formatter.  Could you include which sink you're using and how you've configured it?

Comment: @PatrickSteele I updated the details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From looking at the [source code](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/ee68faec21694d27da94555811bb587a64b6c8d0/src/Serilog/Formatting/Json/JsonFormatter.cs), it doesn't look like the JsonFormatter supports skipping those default properties.  You could create your own ITextFormatter that does what you're looking for.  Here's a quick example (that should not be used in production because it doesn't do any escaping -- it's just for demo purposes):

```
public class SOFormatter : ITextFormatter
{
    public void Format(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write("{");
        foreach (var p in logEvent.Properties)
        {
            output.Write("\"{0}\" : {1}, ", p.Key, p.Value);
        }
        output.Write("}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm using Serilog mongo pkg. Is it possible to remove the default property "MessageTemplate" from the mongo document generated? Thanks

Comment: @pregoli Hey, this is a bit late, but you can definitely do that. You'll have to edit the original source code and remove that portion of the code that generates that key-value.

Answer (score 3):

This question is old but now there is some easy solution for it, so I want to share them.

1. Make sure you have this [Serilog.Expressions Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/serilog.expressions) (version 3.3 at least)
2. You can now configure the `ExpressionTemplate` in code, here is an example:

   ```
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .WriteTo.Console(formatter: new ExpressionTemplate("{ {@t, @mt, @r, @l: if @l = 'Information' then undefined() else @l, @x, ..@p} }\n"))
       .CreateLogger();
   ```
3. Or you can configure `ExpressionTemplate` in the `appSettings.json`, like this

   ```
   {
     "Name": "Console",
     "Args": {
       "formatter": {
         "type": "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions",
         "template": "[{@t:HH:mm:ss} {@l:u3} {Coalesce(SourceContext, '<none>')}] {@m}\n{@x}"
       }
     }
   }
   ```

**Notes**

1. The `formatter` word in the `appSettings` is the name of an argument to a method, So it could be different depending on the sink you are using. 
   For example, I used [Mongodb Sink](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.MongoDB/), so the name of the argument was `mongoDBJsonFormatter` for me
2. I am not explaining the syntax of the `ExpressionTemplate` here, you can consult the following links for more info on that.
3. here is [a good article](https://nblumhardt.com/2020/10/programmable-serilog-formatting/#formatting-json) which explain this in more details
4. here is [Some documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions#formatting-with-expressiontemplate)